# Hide a parent div when filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have timeline with a filter that allows users to show/hide events. The way the CSS is formatted requires that the entire parent (".timeline") be hidden if no matches were made in the filter, otherwise there's a border that remains visible:

[JSFiddle to see example](https://jsfiddle.net/t1pbhy43/1/)

```
<form>
  <p>Topics</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="topic1" id="topic1"><label for="topic1">Topic 1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="topic2" id="topic2"><label for="topic2">Topic 2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="topic3" id="topic3"><label for="topic3">Topic 3</label>
</form>

<form>
<p>
Format
</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="format" value="format1" id="format1"><label for="format1">Format 1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="format" value="format2" id="format2"><label for="format2">Format 2</label>
</form>

<br>

<div class="timeline">
    <div class="event" data-id="event1"
        data-category="topic1 format1">
        Date &amp; Time<br>
        Content
    </div>
    <div class="event" data-id="event2"
        data-category="topic2 format2">
        Date &amp; Time<br>
        Content
    </div>
</div>
```

```
    var $filterCheckboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
    $filterCheckboxes.on('change', function () {
        var selectedFilters = {};
        $filterCheckboxes.filter(':checked').each(function () {
            if (!selectedFilters.hasOwnProperty(this.name)) {
                selectedFilters[this.name] = [];
            }
            selectedFilters[this.name].push(this.value);
        });
        var $filteredResults = $('.event');
        $.each(selectedFilters, function (name, filterValues) {
            $filteredResults = $filteredResults.filter(function () {
                var matched = false,
                    currentFilterValues = $(this).data('category').split(' ');
                $.each(currentFilterValues, function (_, currentFilterValue) {
                    if ($.inArray(currentFilterValue, filterValues) != -1) {
                        matched = true;
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                return matched;
            });
        });
        $('.event').hide().filter($filteredResults).show();
    });
```

I tried including `$('.timeline').hide().filter($filteredResults).show();` to the last line, which works at first, but then when you uncheck boxes none of the elements reappear.

Is there some sort of if/then statement I should be using? Like, `if matched = false { document.getElementsByClassName("timeline").style.display = "none"; };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the Javascript you need

```js
    var $filterCheckboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
    $filterCheckboxes.on('change', function () {
        $('.timeline').show();
        var selectedFilters = {};
        $filterCheckboxes.filter(':checked').each(function () {
            if (!selectedFilters.hasOwnProperty(this.name)) {
                selectedFilters[this.name] = [];
            }
            selectedFilters[this.name].push(this.value);
        });
        var $filteredResults = $('.event');
        $.each(selectedFilters, function (name, filterValues) {
            $filteredResults = $filteredResults.filter(function () {
                var matched = false,
                    currentFilterValues = $(this).data('category').split(' ');
                $.each(currentFilterValues, function (_, currentFilterValue) {
                    if ($.inArray(currentFilterValue, filterValues) != -1) {
                        matched = true;
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                return matched;
            });
        });
        $('.event').hide().filter($filteredResults).show();
        var all_hidden = true;
        $('.event').each(function (index) {
                if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
                all_hidden = false;
            }
        });
        if (all_hidden) {
            $('.timeline').hide();
        }
    });
```

I added an if statement at the end to check if all events are hidden, by looping through all events and checking their visibility with `if ($(this).is(":visible"))`. If they are all hidden it hides the timeline, if not the timeline stays put.

At the start of your function I added a line to make sure the timeline is visible before starting the visibility loop or else all events will be hidden and the code won't work as `$(this).is(":visible")` will always return false.

Comment: awesome. I was even able to take what you did and add another piece that shows/hides some "no results" text if everything is hidden.